# Dynamic value change in for loop in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

Hi how to pass dynamic value in for loop. in `value={{ product.size.0.size }}`
instead of 0 i want to pass index value

```
{% for no_of in product.size %}
{{ forloop.counter }}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label or="">Product Size</label> <input class="form-control" placeholder="Alpha-Numeric characters"
                required="required" type="text" name="product_size" id="product_size" value="{{ product.size.0.size }}">
            <div class="help-block form-text with-errors form-control-feedback"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No you don't. You're already iterating through the actual list, not the numbers.

```
{% for size_item in product.size %}
    ...
    value="{{ size_item.size }}"
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: how to get index value

Comment: What does that mean?